# Getting an error during Mongodb installation with CodeIgniter 3X

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm a beginner with MongoDB.

I wanted to use it with my CodeIgniter 3.x framework. I'm using PHP7.3 and also PHP 5.6 Xampp.

I have also installed some "php extensions" required (like: "php-mongo", so on). Unfortunately, after having installed all that stuff, my webpage throws this error :

```
An Error Was Encountered

The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled
```

I already gave a look to similar questions which were posted several weeks or months ago, but I didn't manage to find a solution to my problem.

Comment: I wonder if you have installed the Mongo extension for one of your PHP versions, but in practice you are using the other installation. Obviously you need to install it for the correct one.

Comment: Try creating a file called `info.php` in your docroot containing the text `<?php phpinfo();` and visit the file in your browser (probably `http://localhost/info.php`). Here you can check the version and what extensions are installed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer...!!  I have checked it with your way but didn't help me to get solve problem. After digging I found that MongoDB library have some issue with that, So I have solve that issue.

Comment: My answer was not a solution. It was a way to determine whether you are accessing the right PHP version, and whether you had installed the Mongo extension in that PHP version.